# Use HotKey Library in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, global-hotkey

I'm trying to use this library: [soffes/HotKey](https://github.com/soffes/HotKey) in an SwiftUI Application for MacOS.
The author describes the usage as follows:

1. Set up Hotkey:

```
let hotKey = HotKey(key: .r, modifiers: [.command, .option])
```

2. set the keyDownHandler and get callbacks for when your hot key is pressed:

```
hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
  print("Pressed at \(Date())")
}
```

My problem is that I don't know where I have to put the Handler. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.
The `keyDownHandler`really just defines what should happen when a hotkey is pressed so you can just put it into the `.onAppear {}` after your body View

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem; I was initializing a hotkey inside my appDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function. I had it declared locally and I think it was getting garbage collected.

The fix for me was to make a `hotKey` property on my appDelegate (although I'm sure you could do the same on any root view or scene if you aren't using an appDelegate) and assign my hotKey to it:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var hotKey: HotKey?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let hotKey = HotKey(key: .six, modifiers: [.command, .option])
        hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
            print("Got hotkey at \(Date())")
        }
        
        self.hotKey = hotKey
    }
}
```